# Flurry IOS Crash with addition log

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, flurry, flurry-analytics

Can I add logEvent when app is before/after crash? Idea is I want to add user account to "crash log" or something data and when app is crash I know in what account occurred crash.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I think you can do it; looking at [iOS SDK Documentation for Flurry](http://flurrydev.github.io/FlurryiOSSDK6xAPI/index.html), you should look at the method

```
(void) + logError:message:error:
```

This method captures an error for reporting to Flurry, so you can use it for add some extra info. See this example:

```
- (void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    [Flurry logError:@"WebView No Load" message:[error localizedDescription] error:error];
}
```

I searched something similar 'time ago for the same reason and I found it this method; I think you can use the parameter **message** for concatenate your info.

PS = I'm really interested in this topic so I continue looking for find some more info, If I'll have something more useful I'll update this answer.

Comment: Ok, thx. I can try write to flurry support with this question. I will inform you here, if I have some news.